# SQL View from multiple database records

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by, sql-view

Clearly a newbie to this platform. I've been a long time reader of stack overflow, but first time poster, so do go easy on me please.

I have 2 databases (within same instance), one for each company. Let's call them company A and company B. Both of these databases have the following columns:
ProductID, Warehouse, Quantity

I would like to create a SQL View where it has 3 columns:
ProductID, Quantity A (from database A), Quantity B (from database B)

I would also like to include the following conditions:

- It should only return results for products that either have stock in Quantity A or Quantity B or Both. It shouldn't return any results if no stock in any of the databases.
- For Quantity A - return results where warehouse = XY and XZ
- For Quantity B - return results where warehouse = XY

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Databases don't contain columns (directly).  They contain tables.  Two companies should be on separate rows within the same *table*, not in separate tables.  You should fix the data model.  Also, tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Sorry I missed that bit out. They're two different databases with identical tables in each database. Hope that makes sense? And it's Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have two separate *tables* for each company that you want to combine at the product level.

One method is `union all` and `group by`:

```
select productid, sum(quantity_a) as quantity_a,
       sum(quantity_b) as quantity_b
from ((select productid, quantity as quantity_a, 0 as quantity_b
       from a
      ) union all
      (select productid, 0 as quantity_a, quantity as quantity_b
       from b
      )
     ) ab
group by productid;
```

Comment: This pointed me exactly where I needed to go, thanks very much :)